# How to update a field for all matching documents in ES queried on the same field?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Is there any easy way to perform the task of updating a field for all matching documents in Elastic Search Index queried on the same field. I am familiar with SQL but not much in Elastic Search.

The above task can be performed in SQL as

```
update TABLE_NAME set COL_NAME_1 = VALUE_2 where COL_NAME_1 = VALUE_1;
```

Similarly, I have come up with query to update documents in ES

```
POST /INDEX/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
      "source": "ctx._source['field1'] = value2"
  },
  "query": {
      "term": {
         "field1": "value1" 
      }
  }
}
```

But this query is not working as expected. The response of this query contains zero failures, zero updates. But I can assure you that there are matching documents for this query on that Index.

Please help me perform acheive my task. Thanks.

Edit:-

The mapping for the field1 is

```
{
   "type": "text",
   "fields": {
      "keyword": {
         "type": "keyword",
         "ignore_above": 256
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you check that your same query is actually returning the result??

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index? especially the `field` field. Most probably as @ElasticsearchNinja said, your query doesn't match anything, which is why you don't see any updates

Comment: Do you get any docs in response for `GET <index>/_search {"query": {
      "term": {
         "field1": "value1" 
      }
  }`

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja, @Opster ES Ninja Nishant  - the same query returned results (already mentioned in the question). @Val mapping for this field is `{
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }`.